# Emacs cannot download whole melpa

Tags: emacs

My Emacs installation cannot download the whole *melpa*:

> Unable to find theme file for ‘solarized-dark’

I added the official code from the melpa webpage and `m-x package-list-packages` and there are only some melpa packages:

```lisp
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
;; Comment/uncomment this line to enable MELPA Stable if desired.  See `package-archive-priorities`
;; and `package-pinned-packages`. Most users will not need or want to do this.
;;(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)


(load-theme 'solarized-dark t)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [GNU Privacy Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard) (GnuPG) keys are not imported, it will not download the whole melpa type:

> `alt-x package-install enter use-package enter

This will trigger downloading GnuPG keys and also use-package is the package which must be installed for installing other packages.